# Apache and Tomcat run on the same server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have currently Apache running on port 80, it has lots of domains setup. I need to install Tomcat 7 and run it also on port 80. I know how to configure it but how do I make my old Apache and Tomcat run on the same port 80 ?

Comment: You can't do that.  You can make Apache forward some virtual domains to Tomcat, but Tomcat has to run on a different port.  This is also a question for serverfault.com rather than stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up by assigning a secondary ip address to your network card. Either google the procedure or get in touch with your system admin (Windows or Unix) for assistance. Once you have the secondary ip address configured, you can setup the second instance of apache to listen to it on port 80. For your convenience you can also have a DNS entry setup for that ip addresss, so that you can access it using a name vs ip address.